# Postgresql - how to find specify string in ANY arrays in the column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column array[] named tags.

i have here f.e.:

```
{{dogs, cats, phones, bottles}}
{{pistols,politican,juices}}
{{dogs,pistols}}
etc..
```

I want to find in all of them f.e. word "dogs" and select only entries with "dogs". I tried to use:

```
SELECT * FROM question WHERE tags[0] = ANY(ARRAY['dogs']);
```

Comment: this answer not working for me.

Comment: Given your sample data, what exactly is the result you want?

Comment: Have you tried "reversing" the `ANY` like `'dogs' = ANY (tags[0])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it the other way round:

```
SELECT * 
FROM question 
WHERE 'dogs' = ANY(tags);
```

The above assumes that `tags` is a one-dimensional array, e.g. `text[]`

Comment: I love you. In my angry i lost easiest result. Thank you.